# How to calculate a Complier Average Causal Effect for a Linear Mixed Model in R?

Tags: r, lme4

I have conducted an experiment that has multiple observation points and pre- and post-intervention nested within individuals. I have analyzed the main findings as follows:

```
lmer(Y~ treatment*time+ (1 | id), data =df)
```

In addition, the data includes information regarding manipulation checks. I wish to calculate a Complier Average Causal Effect for the above code using a `complier` variable. Elsewhere it has been suggested to use such variable as an instrument, however, I have not found any helpful advice regarding how to include an instrument in a `lmer` in `R`. I would appreciate any advice regarding the issue or alternative ways to move foward.

Comment: Needs data and code and results as well as an expanded description of what sort of models is/are being considered to test what sort of hypotheses.

Comment: instrumental variables are more commonly used in econometrics-focused frameworks: have you tried using the `plm` package (e.g. see https://bookdown.org/paul/applied-causal-analysis/packages-functions-plm.html ) ?